# Remove index name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
         Column 1
foo              
Apples          1
Oranges         2
Puppies         3
Ducks           4
```

How to remove `index name` `foo` from that dataframe?
The desired output is like this:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
         Column 1             
Apples          1
Oranges         2
Puppies         3
Ducks           4
```

Comment: `df.index.name = None`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use `del df.index.name`

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
         Column 1
foo
Apples          1
Oranges         2
Puppies         3
Ducks           4

In [17]: del df.index.name

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
         Column 1
Apples          1
Oranges         2
Puppies         3
Ducks           4
```

Comment: With `pandas` version 1.0.3, this does not seem to work anymore. It fails with "AttributeError: can't delete attribute".

Comment: @billjoie do you know how to solve this problem in pandas 1.0.3. , since `del df.index.name` doesn't work

Comment: @mrn, La solution de @EdChum conctionne très bien: `df.index.name = None`

Comment: @billjoie Bless your heart. Been on this for a little while. That del df.index.name doesn't work with later version of pandas.

Comment: Python 3.9.7 and Pandas 1.3.3: AttributeError: can't delete attribute

Answer (score 154):

Alternatively you can just assign `None` to the `index.name` attribute:

```
>>> df.index.name = None
>>> print(df)
         Column 1    
Apples          1
Oranges         2
Puppies         3
Ducks           4
```

Comment: Work perfectly find for Python 3.9.7 with Pandas 1.3.3

Answer (score 143):

Took me way too long to find an answer that actually worked for me.  See below.

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

I'm sure some of these other answers are working for other people, but they definitely didn't work for me :(

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me; using rename_axis() and adding axis=1

Comment: Confirm that this is the only answer that works for me!

Comment: Only answer working for me as well. Some answers work with my other DataFrames, but not with this one. I suppose it is related from the formation of the DataFrame from pivot_table() and reset_index().

Comment: I too am in the group for which the other solutions didn't work. Because my dataframe is the result of a pivot. This label is not the name of the index. It's the former column title from which the current column names came.

Comment: This is what worked for me as well, thanks! In addition, one can use 'inplace=True' with this method as well, if desired.

Answer (score 54):

From version `0.18.0` you can use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
print df
         Column 1
foo              
Apples          1
Oranges         2
Puppies         3
Ducks           4

print df.index.name
foo


print df.rename_axis(None)
         Column 1
Apples          1
Oranges         2
Puppies         3
Ducks           4

print df.rename_axis(None).index.name
None

# To modify the DataFrame itself:
df.rename_axis(None, inplace=True)
print df.index.name
None
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple change -- do it inplace:

```
df_degree.rename_axis(None, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

for your case, just use the following code. tested on pandas                    1.0.1.

```
df = df.rename_axis(index=None)
```