# Transform dataframe and count values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe df that looks like

```
Date Type
2010  A
1998  A
2003  B
2003  C
2007  D
2010  D
2015  B
2015  B
2006  C
2006  C
1998  D
```

I need to transform it and count the occurence of each Type for each year. So my expected output is:

```
    1998 2003 2006 2007 2010 2015
 A   1   0     0     0   1    0
 B   0   1     0     0   0    2 
 C   0   1     2     0   0    0
 D   1   0     0     1   1    0
```

As i understood, i need to use`pivot` here, right?
Something like `df.pivot(index='Type', columns='Data', values=???)`

Comment: Actually I think what you want is [crosstab](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html), not pivot.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864929/creating-one-dataframe-from-another-using-pivot (create a new column filled with 1, then use pivot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pivot_table and pass `len` as the aggregate function:

```
df.pivot_table(index="Type", columns="Date",  aggfunc=len).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[152]: 
Date  1998  2003  2006  2007  2010  2015
Type                                    
A        1     0     0     0     1     0
B        0     1     0     0     0     2
C        0     1     2     0     0     0
D        1     0     0     1     1     0
```

Like [Ajean mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549870/transform-dataframe-and-count-values-in-pandas/37550112#comment62588384_37549870), you can use crosstab too:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Type'], df['Date'])
Out[153]: 
Date  1998  2003  2006  2007  2010  2015
Type                                    
A        1     0     0     0     1     0
B        0     1     0     0     0     2
C        0     1     2     0     0     0
D        1     0     0     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the empty values to show up, you can also use :

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Type']).size().reset_index()
```

Which would give :

```
   Date Type  0
0  1998    A  1
1  1998    D  1
2  2003    B  1
3  2003    C  1
4  2006    C  2
5  2007    D  1
6  2010    A  1
7  2010    D  1
8  2015    B  2
```