# How to drop first row using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've searched at other questions related to dropping rows but could not find one that worked:

I have a CSV file exported from the tool screaming frog that looks like this:

```
Internal - HTML |               |             |
--------------- | --------------|-------------|
   Address      |   Content     | Status Code |
----------------|---------------|-------------|
www.example.com |   text/html   |   200       |
```

I want to remove the first row that contains 'Internal - HTML'. When analyzing it with `df.keys()` I get this information" `Index(['Internal - HTML'], dtype='object')`.

I want to use the second row as the Index, which contains the correct column labels.

When I use the code:

```
a = pandas.read_csv("internal_html.csv", encoding="utf-8")
a.drop('Internal - HTML')
a.head(3)
```

I get this error: `KeyError: 'Internal - HTML'`

I also tried what was suggested here [Remove index name in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765548/remove-index-name-in-pandas][1]) and also tried resetting the index:

```
a = pandas.read_csv("internal_html.csv", encoding="utf-8")
a.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
a.head(3)
```

None of the options above worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add `header` as a parameter in the first call, to use column names and start of data :

```
a = pandas.read_csv("internal_html.csv", encoding="utf-8", header=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure about how data is in `csv`, but I think you can use `skiprows=1` while reading the `csv`:

```
a = pd.read_csv("internal_html.csv", encoding="utf-8")
a.keys()
```

Output:

```
Index(['Internal - HTML'], dtype='object')
```

Looking at `df` (*Assuming data is in following format*):

```
print(a)
```

Output:

```
                            Internal - HTML
Address            Content   Status Code   
www.example.com   text/html     200
```

Now, using `skiprows` to read the `.csv` file:

```
a = pd.read_csv("internal_html.csv", encoding="utf-8", skiprows=1)
print(a.keys())
```

Output:

```
Index(['Address', '   Content', 'Status Code'], dtype='object')
```

Observing dataframe `a`:

```
print(a)
```

Output:

```
           Address      Content       Status Code
  0  www.example.com    text/html     200
```