# remove pandas index name?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get rid of column/column name from pandas dataframe that I get after using pivot. I am not sure

```
temp = {'NOL' : [2016,2016,2016,2017, 2017, 2017],
   'A1': ['M1','M2', 'M3','M1','M2', 'M3'],
   'Val':[100, 110, 130, 140, 150, 160]}
dd = pd.DataFrame(temp)
dd2 = dd.pivot(index = 'A1', columns = 'NOL', values='Val').reset_index()

dd2.columns give me Index(['A1', 2016, 2017], dtype='object', name='NOL')
```

Here I want to get rid of NOL index or column with NOL. I've [tried options here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765548/remove-index-name-in-pandas). with `dd2.index.name = None` and `del dd2.index.name` but it does not work.

Comment: Are you referring to the columns name attribute? if so then you want `dd2.columns.name = None` There is a dupe of this somewhere

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you are really good at finding dupes. : )