# Removing index name from df created with pivot_table()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Well I checked the question [Remove index name in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765548/remove-index-name-in-pandas), and it is not working for my case.

So I had a df, I normalized it with pandas `melt`, then I denormalize it with `pivot_table`. Now I have the following df, but I want to remove this index name `variable`.

Here is the df:

```
df
variable   Site        Process  cap-lo    cap-up  depreciation  ...    inv-cost      max-grad  min-fraction  var-cost  wacc
0           Mid  Biomass plant     0.0    5000.0          25.0  ...    875000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       1.4  0.07
1           Mid     Coal plant     0.0       0.0          40.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.6  0.07
2           Mid      Gas plant     0.0   80000.0          30.0  ...    450000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       1.6  0.07
3           Mid    Hydro plant     0.0    1400.0          50.0  ...   1600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
4           Mid  Lignite plant     0.0   60000.0          40.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.6  0.07
5           Mid    Solar plant     0.0  160000.0          25.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
6           Mid     Wind plant     0.0   13000.0          25.0  ...   1500000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
7         North  Biomass plant     0.0    6000.0          25.0  ...    875000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       1.4  0.07
8         North     Coal plant     0.0  100000.0          40.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.6  0.07
9         North      Gas plant     0.0  100000.0          30.0  ...    450000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       1.6  0.07
10        North    Hydro plant     0.0   20000.0          50.0  ...   1600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
11        North  Lignite plant     0.0       0.0          40.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.6  0.07
12        North    Solar plant     0.0    3000.0          25.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
13        North     Wind plant     0.0   60000.0          25.0  ...   1500000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
14        South  Biomass plant     0.0       0.0          25.0  ...    875000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       1.4  0.07
15        South     Coal plant     0.0  100000.0          40.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.6  0.07
16        South      Gas plant     0.0  100000.0          30.0  ...    450000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       1.6  0.07
17        South    Hydro plant     0.0       0.0          50.0  ...   1600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
18        South  Lignite plant     0.0       0.0          40.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.6  0.07
19        South    Solar plant     0.0  600000.0          25.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
20        South     Wind plant     0.0  200000.0          25.0  ...   1500000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
```

**I want to remove this `variable` which is above the indexes. How would I do that?**

It is probably not an index name, but a column name... I just want to remove the variable.

PS: `df.index.name = 'blah'` does following:

```
df
variable   Site        Process  cap-lo    cap-up  depreciation  ...    inv-cost      max-grad  min-fraction  var-cost  wacc
blah                                                            ...                                                        
0           Mid  Biomass plant     0.0    5000.0          25.0  ...    875000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       1.4  0.07
1           Mid     Coal plant     0.0       0.0          40.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.6  0.07
2           Mid      Gas plant     0.0   80000.0          30.0  ...    450000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       1.6  0.07
3           Mid    Hydro plant     0.0    1400.0          50.0  ...   1600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
4           Mid  Lignite plant     0.0   60000.0          40.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.6  0.07
5           Mid    Solar plant     0.0  160000.0          25.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
6           Mid     Wind plant     0.0   13000.0          25.0  ...   1500000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
7         North  Biomass plant     0.0    6000.0          25.0  ...    875000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       1.4  0.07
8         North     Coal plant     0.0  100000.0          40.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.6  0.07
9         North      Gas plant     0.0  100000.0          30.0  ...    450000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       1.6  0.07
10        North    Hydro plant     0.0   20000.0          50.0  ...   1600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
11        North  Lignite plant     0.0       0.0          40.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.6  0.07
12        North    Solar plant     0.0    3000.0          25.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
13        North     Wind plant     0.0   60000.0          25.0  ...   1500000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
14        South  Biomass plant     0.0       0.0          25.0  ...    875000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       1.4  0.07
15        South     Coal plant     0.0  100000.0          40.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.6  0.07
16        South      Gas plant     0.0  100000.0          30.0  ...    450000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       1.6  0.07
17        South    Hydro plant     0.0       0.0          50.0  ...   1600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
18        South  Lignite plant     0.0       0.0          40.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.6  0.07
19        South    Solar plant     0.0  600000.0          25.0  ...    600000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
20        South     Wind plant     0.0  200000.0          25.0  ...   1500000.0  1.500000e+15           0.0       0.0  0.07
```

Comment: you can set the index name to what you want df.index.name = "blah"

Comment: It just adds index "blah", does not remove variable. I am guessing variable is not the index...

Comment: try df.index.name = None

Comment: if that doesnt work you probably have a multiindex. you can try df.reset_index

Comment: Try `df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: @Abhi it works :) write an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)  
# df.columns.name = None

# To remove index label
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=0)
# df.index.name = None
```

Comment: can u also explain why rename index here not working but rename axis and why it is axis=1... :) Just for a better answer so people can understand the difference and when they should use this

Comment: @oakca It's not an index name rather a column name and axis tells what to rename here `0: index and 1: columns`.

Comment: I meant explain it in ur answer :) but anyway