# how to rename pandas dataframe index column and have it print on same line/row as column headings?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rename, z-index

When I rename my dataframe's index column it doesn't print on o the same line as my column headings. How do I fix this so the Index colum heading prints on the same row as the other column headings?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove index name in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765548/remove-index-name-in-pandas)

Comment: You could try print(df.to_markdown())

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you merely want to adjust, how the DataFrame is **printed** in the **console**, this seems to not be possible.
Pandas offers several possibilities to adjust how values are displayed by default:
[pandas options](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html)

However, the placement of the index header seems to not be included here.
Obviously, if you intend to export the DataFrame in a text file, website, or anything else - there are several possibilites to adjust the styling.